# Drupal PHP error zval can't be arrays

Tags: php, drupal

Im getting this error 
Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in **Unknown** on line **0**

on a site that was built in drupal, it appears to be crashing httpd.exe

Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.14.0, time stamp 0x4aeb9704, faulting module php5ts.dll, version 5.3.1.0, time stamp 0x4b06c41d, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x000c31b6, process id 0x1410, application start time 0x01cb031455273060.

I never built the site and have never touched drupal or php.

Can anyone shed light on what might be happening?

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Drupal related problem, this is PHP module compilation problem.

Comment: any ideas how to locate the issue, i dont even know what page is causing the problem.

Comment: the problem goes far beyond "a page", there is something very wrong with your server setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ever heard of Google? You look at "Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.14.0, time stamp 0x4aeb9704, faulting module php5ts.dll" it's immediately clear that you want to delete the version string (as that can be variable) and the time stamp, you get "Faulting application httpd.exe faulting module php5ts.dll". Even with quotes you get nine results, and the first happens to solve your problem.

Comment: My bad, I Googled zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0
not thehttpd.exe.
I shall try this and let you know if it works

Thanks
Sp