# Fatal error: Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, fatal-error

My website was working fine, but yesterday some pages are not working, not even showing me single character on page, i did contact my host, they said that they are getting this error "Fatal error: Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0" can anyone please help me how to solve this issue, who can fix it? is this PHP version issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal PHP error zval can't be arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965884/drupal-php-error-zval-cant-be-arrays)

Comment: No this is not the duplicate, as i am not using Drupal, using simple php, if this is php compilation issue so can you please let me know how to solve it? As it was working fine till Saturday but now it is not.

Comment: Read the answers in the linked question - that is not a drupal related error.

Comment: Yes i did read it, they are saying that "PHP module compilation problem" so does this mean i have to again contact my host to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you search on google as chx recommends in his post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2983787/309163)? You will get dozens of results: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fatal+error%3A+Internal+zval%27s+can%27t+be+arrays%2C+objects+or+resources%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8. If you already followed the steps outlined in the articles found there, please add details what you tried.